# Cannot access to another class inside Requirejs module

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript, requirejs

I can't access my "App" object despite I require it inside my module with the defined statement. Could you explain me please why my code is not working.

This is my main.js file :

```
require(['underscore', 'backbone', 'App'], function(_, Backbone, App) {

    window.App = new App();
    Backbone.history.start();
    return window.App.init();
```

});

This is my app.js file :

```
define(['underscore', 'backbone', 'Views/ApplicationView'], function(_, Backbone, ApplicationView) {
    'use strict';
    var App;
    return App = (function() {

        function App() {

            this.init = __bind(this.init, this);
        }

        App.prototype.init = function() {

            this.view = new ApplicationView();
       };

       return App;

    })();
});
```

And finally my applicationView.js

```
define(['underscore', 'backbone', 'views/AbstractView', 'App'], function(_, Backbone, AbstractView, App) {
    'use strict';
    var RegisterView;
    return RegisterView = (function(_super) {
        __extends(RegisterView, _super);

        function RegisterView() {
            this.init = __bind(this.init, this);
            return RegisterView.__super__.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
        }



        RegisterView.prototype.init = function() {

            RegisterView.__super__.init.apply(this, arguments);
            this.model = App.user; // APP IS UNDEFINED
        };

    })(AbstractView);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only issue I'm seeing with this code is a circular dependency. In general you want to design your code to avoid them. If you can't then, the code above should be modified so that the line that assigns `this.model` (in `RegisterView.prototype.init`) is like this:

```
this.model = require("App").user;
```

It has to be this way because the `App` that the module's factory function (the anonymous function given to `define`) will get will necessarily be `undefined` because by the time RequireJS loads this module, the module for `App` has not yet finished loading. Performing the `require` call like above causes RequireJS to fetch the value later, when the module for `App` has finished loading.

Documented [here](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#circular).

Comment: Thanks for your explanations, but when I'm doing require("App"), that return me the constructor of the App variable. And then the user model is undefined

Comment: Your comment makes it sound like what you actually want is `this.model = window.App.user`, which will get the `App` object that you've set on `window`. If so, then it is not clear at all to me why you put `App` in the list of dependencies in your `applicationView.js` file.